# Get variable name from NameError object

Tags: python

if I catch a `NameError` exception using `except`:

```
try:
    print(unknownVar)
except NameError as ne:
    print(ne)
```

I get a string like :

```
NameError: name 'unknownVar' is not defined
```

I work in the context of eval'ed expressions and it whould be a useful information to me if I could obtain only the variable name (here "unknownVar" alone) and not the full string. I did not find an attribute for example in the NameError object to get it (perhaps does it exists, but I did not find it). Is there something better than parsing this string to do to get the information I need ?

Best Regards
   Mikhaël

Comment: Actually, that's not the output; the output will be `name 'unknownVar' is not defined` without the `NameError: ` part.

Comment: @Anwarvic Yes it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it using regex:

```
import re
try:
    print(unknownVar)
except NameError as ne:
    var_name = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", str(ne))[0] 
    print(var_name) # output: unknownVar
```

Comment: Ok. Sounds a little bit ugly, I am surprized the most fundamental information of the var name itself cannot be obtained ...

Thanks a lot, Mikhaël

Comment: This one seems better than chain of `split`, `strip` and list indexing. It would be also nice to wrap it into a function.

Comment: What is ugly is not the idea of using a regular expression. What is ugly is that Python conducts us to require to string parsing to extract this information, this is not normal in my mind. Simply adding a field with the variable name would not be technically incredible and avoid such  surprizing hack.

Answer (score 1):

Extract it from the string:

`ne.args[0].split()[1].strip("'")`

Comment: Ok. Sounds a little bit ugly, I am surprized the most fundamental information of the var name itself cannot be obtained ...

Thanks a lot, Mikhaël

Comment: I would use `str(ne)` instead of `ne.args[0]` to obtain the message since it seems a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, error messages are not exactly Python's strong suit.  However, there is actually an alternative to parsing the string, but it is quite "hacky" and only works with *CPython* (i.e. this will fail with *PyPy*, *Jython*, etc.).

The idea is to extract the name of whatever you wanted to load from the underlying code object.

```py
import sys
import opcode

def extract_name():
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]        # get the traceback
    while tb.tb_next is not None:
        tb = tb.tb_next
    instr_pos = tb.tb_lasti       # the index of the "current" instruction
    frame = tb.tb_frame           
    code = frame.f_code           # the code object
    instruction = opcode.opname[code.co_code[instr_pos]]
    arg = code.co_code[instr_pos + 1]
    if instruction == 'LOAD_FAST':
        return code.co_varnames[arg]
    else:
        return code.co_names[arg]

def test(s):
    try:
        exec(s)
    except NameError:
        name = extract_name()
        print(name)

test("print(x + y)")
```

---

### 1. The Background of Code Object

Python compiles the original Python source code into bytecode and then executes that bytecode.  The code is stored in "code objects", which are (partly) documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).  For our purpose, the following will suffice:

```py
class CodeObject:
    co_code: bytes       # the bytecode instructions
    co_varnames: tuple   # names of local variables and parameters
    co_names: tuple      # all other names
```

If some code produces a `NameError`, it failed to load a specific name.  That name must be either in the `co_names` or `co_varnames` tuple.  All we have to figure out is which one.

While the code objects desribe the code statically, we also need a dynamic object that tells us the value of local variables and which instruction we are currently executing.  This role is fulfilled by the "frame" (leaving out irrelevant details):

```py
class Frame:
    f_code: CodeObject     # the code object (see above)
    f_lasti: int           # the instruction currently executed
```

You could think of the interpreter as basically doing the following:

```py
def runCode(code):
    frame = create_new_frame(code)
    while True:
        i = frame.f_lasti
        opcode = frame.f_code.co_code[i]
        arg    = frame.f_code.co_code[i+1]
        exec_opcode(opcode, arg)
        frame.f_lasti += 2
```

The code to load a name then has a form like this:

- `LOAD_NAME   3` (the actual name is `co_names[3]`)
- `LOAD_GLOBAL 3` (the actual name is `co_names[3]`)
- `LOAD_FAST   3` (the actual name is `co_varnames[3]`)

You can see that we have to distinguish between `LOAD_FAST` (i.e. load a local variable) and all other `LOAD_X` opcodes.

### 2. Getting The Right Name

When an error occurs, we need to go through the *stacktrace*/*traceback* until we find the *frame* in which the error occurred.  From the frame we then get the *code object* with the list of all names and instructions, extract the instruction and argument that led to the error and thus the *name*.

We retrieve the traceback with `sys.exc_info()[2]`.  The actual frame and traceback we are interested in is the very last one (this is what you can read in the line `Traceback (most recent call last):` whenever a runtime error occurs):

```py
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]        # get the traceback
    while tb.tb_next is not None:
        tb = tb.tb_next
```

This traceback object then contains two information of importance to us: the *frame* `tb_frame` and the *instruction pointer* `tb_last` where the error occurred.  From the frame we then extract the *code object*:

```py
    instr_pos = tb.tb_lasti       # the index of the "current" instruction
    frame = tb.tb_frame           
    code = frame.f_code           # the code object
```

Since the byte encoding the instruction can change with different Python versions, we want to get the human-readable form, which is more stable.  We need that so that we can distinguish between local variables all others:

```py
    instruction = opcode.opname[code.co_code[instr_pos]]
    arg = code.co_code[instr_pos + 1]
    if instruction == 'LOAD_FAST':
        return code.co_varnames[arg]
    else:
        return code.co_names[arg]
```

### 3. Caveat

If the code object uses more than 255 names, a single byte will no longer be enough as index into the tuples with all names.  In that case, the bytecode allows for an extension prefix, which is not taken into account here.  But for most code objects, this should work just fine.

As mentioned in the beginning, this is a rather hacky method that is based on internals of Python that might change (although this is rather unlikely).  Nonetheless, it is fun taking Python apart this way, isn't it ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot, very intersting post !
I was surprized when parsing the error was required to reach my target, as most things in Python are quite clean. Hope this management of Errors will be updated in the future.
Thanks a lot for your time @Tobias.